# Android Intent.getStringExtra() returns null

Tags: android, string, android-intent, null, extras

This is how strings are being added to Extras:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("Name", edt_name.getText());
i.putExtra("Description", edt_desc.getText());
i.putExtra("Priority", skb_prior.getProgress());
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

This is how I try to extract them in `onActivityResult()`:

```
String name = data.getStringExtra("Name");
String desc = data.getStringExtra("Description");
int prior   = data.getIntExtra("Priority", 50);
```

But after the second code block `name` and `desc` are `null`'s, though `prior` has it's proper value.
Moreover, in debugger I can see, that `data.mExtras.mMap` contains needed Strings, but only after first request to it.

Comment: Are you sure `prior` has proper value and not default one (50) which you are setting?

Comment: Yes, but the problem was in `edt_name.getText()`, which returns not `String` but some heir class, may be?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

When you insert your `Extras` trying adding `.toString()`

```
i.putExtra("Name", edt_name.getText().toString());
```

You are seeing the `CharSequence` value in there but you need to convert it to a `String` to call `getStringExtra()`. Obviously, just do this for the `Strings`. You see the correct value for your `int` because that is done correctly

Comment: Thanks, it works, as well as `"" + edt_name.getText()`, which looks not as pretty :)

Comment: It works because `""` is a String literal and you're adding to it.  It works the same way as `"" + 2` comes out to `"2"`.  Whatever is being added to the literal is converted to a String via their own class's `toString` function.

Comment: @codeMagic, Why do you say that it's an `object`? Isn't it `CharSequence`?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, it would actually return a [charSequence](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.getText%28%29)

Comment: @codeMagic In my case, issue is not this one though, as I tried to use same receiver for different Alarms this issue triggered, don't know why? but I end up adding each individually it worked, the purpose of intent in this new approach is now gone..