# Null values in service class android

Tags: java, android, service

I am getting `null` values in service class :-

```
if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
    matchName = intent.getStringExtra("match");
    matchDate = intent.getStringExtra("time");
    Log.d(" Service Match ", intent.getExtras().toString());
}
```

//onCreate Code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   Button match1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.match1);
   match1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
    inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    SimpleDateFormat nativeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
    nativeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

    SimpleDateFormat nativeFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");

    String inpt = matchTimeInGMT(v); // "2014-03-22 8:45:00 PM";
    Button matchButton = (Button) v;
    String matchName = "ABC vs DEF";


    try {
        inptdate = inputFormat.parse(inpt);
        date2 = nativeFormat.format(inptdate);
        endTime.setTime(nativeFormat.parse(date2));
        // endTime.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", endTime.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
        intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY;COUNT=1");
        intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra("title", matchName);

        startActivity(intent);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(endTime.getTime());

        Intent svc = new Intent(this,MyAlarmService.class);
        svc.setAction("matchTime");
        svc.putExtra("match", matchName.toString());
        svc.putExtra("time", nativeFormat1.format(cal.getTime()).toString());
        startService(svc);

         PendingIntent alarmIntent;
        Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(FIXTURE.this, MyReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(FIXTURE.this, 0,
                myIntent1, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, endTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                alarmIntent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Log output -`Bundle[{time=2014-03-25 12:20 AM, match=ABC Vs DEF}]`

I am getting values for `match` and `time` but not getting assigned to `matchName` and `matchDate` variables. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555750/android-intent-getstringextra-returns-null Check this

Comment: @paritosh Were you able to solve this problem ?