# Passing username after Facebook to another activity -Xamarin

Tags: c#, android

I am using intent to pass my data from one activity(auth page) to another activity to have access to the Facebook loggedIn user. I am not seeing any error in my code but the text to display the username returns empty(blank).
What is missing in here? I followed answers of sample issues on S.O to achieve this.

**auth.cs**

```
mProfileTracker = new MyProfileTracker();
            mProfileTracker.mOnProfileChanged +=  FindFaceBookUserProfile;
            mProfileTracker.StartTracking();

    private void FindFaceBookUserProfile(object sender, OnProfileChangeEventArgs e)
            {
                        LoggedInUserName.Text = position.FindProfile.Name;
                        LoggedInUserLastName.Text = position.FindProfile.Name;
        MajorActivity));
                        intent.PutExtra(MajorActivity.EXTRA_NAME, LoggedInUserName.Text);
                        this.StartActivity(intent);

                    }

public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
            LoginResult loginResult = result as LoginResult;
            Console.WriteLine(loginResult.AccessToken.UserId);
             GetId= loginResult.AccessToken.UserId;
        }
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)

        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            mCallbackManager.OnActivityResult(requestCode, (int)resultCode, data );
        }
```

**MajorActivity**

```
        public const string EXTRA_NAME = "UserName";
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            string UserName = Intent.GetStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME);
}

var headerView = navigationView.GetHeaderView(0);
GetUserName= headerView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.loginUser);
GetUserName.Text = UserName;
```

Comment: please post your code for LoggedInUserName as well

Comment: @RedM, i am able to authenticate my users. When i output LoggedInUserName in auth.cs, i am able to see the name. But i am trying to pass the data to MajorActivity's navigation view. The problems seems to come from the intent part.. I am sure :) Code updated

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to extract string in your intent. You need to put a string as well I believe. try

```
intent.PutExtra(MajorActivity.EXTRA_NAME, LoggedInUserName.toString());
```

Reference [Android Intent.getStringExtra() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555750/android-intent-getstringextra-returns-null)

Comment: `intent.PutExtra(MajorActivity.EXTRA_NAME, LoggedInUserName.Text.toString())`; this is what i have now.. it still blank. I don't get an error running the app. App works fine but text is blank. Please note i did some little changes to my code above. That is LoggedInUserName.Text

Comment: This part should be inside the onCreate method. Because your UserName String is local to that method.

    var headerView = navigationView.GetHeaderView(0);
GetUserName= headerView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.loginUser);
GetUserName.Text = UserName;

Comment: It is already in my onCreate Method :) but when i set GetUserName.Text  ="Hello" for instance, it works. Could it be that, the UserName is not reaching or something?

Comment: ok do this. Make String USername a global variable and try. If that doesn't work put a breakpoint there and run it in debug mode and check what value string UserName gets when you evaluate that expression at that line  

       string UserName = Intent.GetStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME);

Comment: i used a global variable for Username now. It is not working and i just consoled the Username. Looking at my log cat, nothing is pushed from the auth.cs. That is why it is blank. The baseActivity runs before the auth i am quite sure. please note: MajorActivity is a baseClass and auth.cs is mapped to be MajorActivity like (Auth: MajorActivity)

Comment: LoggedInUserName.Text is not empty in your auth.cs class right ? you checked it

Comment: no it not empty.. I am able to see the name in the auth.cs

Comment: replace `intent.PutExtra(MajorActivity.EXTRA_NAME, LoggedInUserName.Text);` with `intent.PutExtra(MajorActivity.EXTRA_NAME, LoggedInUserName.Text.toString());`. Also,  check in console values of   `MajorActivity.EXTRA` and `LoggedInUserName.Text.toString()`  right after this line `

Comment: I have been running series of test.After the consoling the values, i see the all the necessary data i want to pass. So the problem now is from the Major activity. How to get the data been passed because i just did a console test in the Major class and i am not receiving the data

Answer (score 0):

In your auth.cs, I do not see you allocation new memory for your intent, so try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MajorActivity.class);
i.putExtra(MajorActivity.EXTRA_NAME, LoggedInUserName.Text);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in your MajorActivity.class, do this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString(MajorActivity.EXTRA_NAME);
}
```

Comment: I am actually using Xamarin.Droid. (C#). Looks like your more of Java

Comment: yeah, I'm more Java. Can you translate this logic into your code though?

Comment: I would have look into the Xamarin forums but i get the logic

Comment: Looking at Xamarin, it is done just the way i have mine. I have actually used this in one of my activities and it worked fine. I can't really tell why my code wouldn't work